# Generating in memory schema from jaxb class

Tags: java, validation, jaxb

I have inherited a terrible mess of XSDs. I can't change the end schema, but I can, if necessary, control the files themselves.

I have two XSD files (ok, lots more, but it's an example) (also, I realize I misspelled Address. Clients are using it that way now. My bad)

Schema1:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns="http://Schema1" targetNamespace="http://Schema1" xmlns:s2="http://Schema2" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:import namespace="http://Schema2" schemaLocation="Schema2.xsd.xsd"/>
    <xsd:element name="Adderess">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element ref="s2:StreetAddress" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Schema 2:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns="http://Schema2" targetNamespace="http://Schema2" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:element name="StreetAddress" type="xsd:string" />
</xsd:schema>
```

Using JAXB RI, I get this in my java class:

```
public static class Adderess
        implements Serializable
    {

        @XmlElement(name = "StreetAddress", namespace = "http://Schema2")
        protected String streetAddress;
 }
```

At runtime, to validate the XML clients send in, I use:

```
final List<ByteArrayOutputStream> outs = new ArrayList<ByteArrayOutputStream>();

    try
    {
        jc.generateSchema(new SchemaOutputResolver(){
            @Override public Result createOutput(String namespaceUri, String suggestedFileName) throws IOException
            {
                // Stream the schema for this specified namespace

                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                outs.add(out);
                StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(out);
                streamResult.setSystemId("");
                return streamResult;                }

        });
    }
```

BUT.....
that generates THIS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" targetNamespace="http://Schema1" xmlns:ns1="http://Schema2" xmlns:tns="http://Schema1" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:import namespace="http://Schema2"/>
    <xs:element name="InputData" form="qualified">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="StreetAddress" type="xs:string" form="qualified" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:sequence>
        <xs:complexType>
    <xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The crux is, when I ref a complex type from another namespace, it works fine on the in memory schema gen. When I ref an element that is a primitive type (like, in this case, a String), the in-memory generated schema doesn't seem to get that it's in another namespace, so my XML validation fails.

I can do some cludgy stuff, like put this in Schema2 instead:

```
<xsd:element name="StreetAddress">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:simpleContent>
            <xsd:extension base="xsd:string"></xsd:extension>
        </xsd:simpleContent>    
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

and that will work, but I have a lot of situations like this, and that's not exactly a great solution to begin with.

Please, anyone, any ideas?